# How to install DBD::Advantage

Tags: windows, linux, perl, dbi, advantage-database-server

I have tried using DBD::Advantage on both Linux and Windows with no luck.  The Windows version comes with what appears to be a full fledged installer, but it leaves behind the DBD-Advantage-8.10.tar.gz.  Under Linux, I had done the `make && make test && make install` series, but regardless I get the following error on both platforms.

```
install_driver(Advantage) failed: Can't locate loadable object for module
DBD::Advantage in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 ...... several other folders.
```

- AdvantageDatabase 8.1
- Perl version is 5.12.4 on Linux and 5.12.3 Strawberry Perl on Win2008.

Comment: Presumably, on Linux, you also did the `perl Makefile.PL` step so that the `make` actually had a chance of working.  And you saw the module being installed?

Comment: On Windows, do not have a windows dev machine to compile and since it came with an installer...    On Linux, Yes, did the perl Makefile.PL thing, had warnings on the machine last night and some of the tests failed.  Nothing clear that it failed.

Answer (score 1):

From the [readme.txt] included with the install:

======

The Advantage DBI Driver is contained in the DBD-Advantage.X.XX.tar.gz file. You can extract it by running:
     tar -zxvf DBD-Advantage.X.XX.tar.gz

======

On Windows you should be able to extract the file using a utility such as winrar

Comment: or 7z or since i already have perl installed, perl archive::tar extract(file.tar.gz),   but since it came with an installation program, i am not sure why i would need it.  Makefile.PL is inside this tar.gz.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the module in your @INC path,   the install probably failed.  I'd try to manually add the package via the perl ./Makefile.PL and see if that fails.

If the module *is* in the @INC path, it may just be a permissions issue.